# PlayN: GroupLayer.add( layer) seems to ignore layer's depth attribute

Tags: playn

Suppose I have 4 layer, A,B,C,D  with layer.depth() of 1, 4, 2, 3.

when I add the those layer to parent, by using groupLayer.add(layer), the index (ala, depth,) of them added seems to ignore the 'depth()' attribute and the result is according only to the order when I add them.

Not sure if it's a implementation bug or I have the wrong usage semantic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is your problem but it's definitely mine right now.

I'm pretty certain layer depth only obeys the depth value **within** a group. 
If you nest groups (like for parts of a character), I think the layer(s) in higher level groups will always be drawn above the layer(s) in lower level groups.
I'm running into this issue now when trying to create a puppet-like character with lots of image layers arranged in a group layer hierarchy of body parts.
The torso needs to be at the top of the transformation hierarchy but some layers need to be drawn on top of the torso as well. Currently, I don't think you can do this with a single group layer hierarchy with image layers as children.

Answer (score 0):

`GroupLayer.add(layer, depth)` [has been deprecated](http://docs.playn.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html). Instead you should use `Layer.setDepth`.

Comment: the Layer.setDepth() behave the same (ie, doesn't seems to have any effect).

Comment: What if you set the depth after you add them?